# Pig - date string to long conversion

Tags: apache-pig

I have some date values in the source text file, like column 3 below

```
123|text|2000-02-05 01:00:00-0500|true
```

how can I convert them to corresponding long value in Pig latin? Thanks.

```
a = load 'test.txt';
b = <what should be here>(a);
dump b; --output contains long value for column 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UDFs from [Piggybank](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html#piggybank) to convert you date string to ISO format using the [CustomFormatToISO UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/CustomFormatToISO.html) and then convert your ISO formatted date to Unix milliseconds using the [ISOToUnix UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/ISOToUnix.html).

Starting with pig 0.11 you can use the DateTime type and call the [ToUnixTime](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToUnixTime.html) builtin UDF.

You can also write your own UDF for that problem, it's really simple.

Comment: Which version of Pig are you using? Because starting with pig 0.11 you  do not need to use Piggybank anymore. You can use the DateTime type and call the ToUnixTime builtin UDF (http://de.slideshare.net/hortonworks/new-features-in-pig-011)

Comment: I'm using 0.10.1, but I can upgrade to 0.11.x. I'll try both. Thanks again.

Comment: UDF works perfect for me: b = FOREACH a generate ISOToUnix(CustomFormatToISO(c3, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ')) AS unixTime:long; I'll try 0.11 next.

Comment: The 0.11 solution works for me too: b = FOREACH a GENERATE ToUnixTime(ToDate(c3, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ')); Fred, you saved me time for searching this, thanks!